# Help with Chainz Galaxy

Tags: software-center, games, proprietary

I just bought Chainz Galaxy from USC, but it does not work. I tried to contact MumboJumbo support, but they didn't help me at all... Thanks in advance

Here's the output when I run it from the terminal

```
willian@willian-Inspiron:~$ /opt/Chainz/Chainz 

(HotBox:3256): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(HotBox:3256): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(HotBox:3256): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",

(HotBox:3256): Gtk-WARNING **: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Lua script executedPanic error in file "/home/ubuntu/Shared/HotSource_v5/HotEngine/Common/OpenGL/OpenGLTexture.cpp", line 687:
  Failed to create OpenGL texture (error code: 0x500, size: 1024x768 -> 1024x1024, format: 5)
Aborted
willian@willian-Inspiron:~$
```

Some useful information

```
willian@willian-Inspiron:~$ uname -a
Linux willian-Inspiron 3.0.0-13-generic-pae #22-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 2 15:17:35 UTC 2011 i686 i686 i386 GNU/Linux

willian@willian-Inspiron:~$ lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)

willian@willian-Inspiron:~$ glxinfo | grep GL
    GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, 
    GLX_MESA_swap_control, GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, 
    GLX_SGI_make_current_read, GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, 
    GLX_SGIS_multisample, GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, 
    GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, 
    GLX_INTEL_swap_event
GLX version: 1.4
GLX extensions:
    GLX_ARB_get_proc_address, GLX_ARB_multisample, GLX_EXT_import_context, 
    GLX_EXT_visual_info, GLX_EXT_visual_rating, GLX_MESA_copy_sub_buffer, 
    GLX_MESA_multithread_makecurrent, GLX_MESA_swap_control, 
    GLX_OML_swap_method, GLX_OML_sync_control, GLX_SGI_make_current_read, 
    GLX_SGI_swap_control, GLX_SGI_video_sync, GLX_SGIS_multisample, 
    GLX_SGIX_fbconfig, GLX_SGIX_pbuffer, GLX_SGIX_visual_select_group, 
    GLX_EXT_texture_from_pixmap, GLX_INTEL_swap_event
OpenGL vendor string: Tungsten Graphics, Inc
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ironlake Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
OpenGL version string: 2.1 Mesa 7.11
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.20
OpenGL extensions:
    GL_ARB_multisample, GL_EXT_abgr, GL_EXT_bgra, GL_EXT_blend_color, 
    GL_EXT_blend_logic_op, GL_EXT_blend_minmax, GL_EXT_blend_subtract, 
    GL_EXT_copy_texture, GL_EXT_polygon_offset, GL_EXT_subtexture, 
    GL_EXT_texture_object, GL_EXT_vertex_array, GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array, 
    GL_EXT_texture, GL_EXT_texture3D, GL_IBM_rasterpos_clip, 
    GL_ARB_point_parameters, GL_EXT_draw_range_elements, GL_EXT_packed_pixels, 
    GL_EXT_point_parameters, GL_EXT_rescale_normal, 
    GL_EXT_separate_specular_color, GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap, GL_SGIS_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp, GL_SGIS_texture_lod, GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GL_ARB_multitexture, GL_EXT_framebuffer_sRGB, 
    GL_IBM_multimode_draw_arrays, GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat, 
    GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1, GL_ARB_texture_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_add, GL_ARB_transpose_matrix, 
    GL_EXT_blend_func_separate, GL_EXT_fog_coord, GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays, 
    GL_EXT_secondary_color, GL_EXT_texture_env_add, 
    GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic, GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias, 
    GL_INGR_blend_func_separate, GL_NV_blend_square, GL_NV_light_max_exponent, 
    GL_NV_texgen_reflection, GL_NV_texture_env_combine4, 
    GL_SUN_multi_draw_arrays, GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression, GL_EXT_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_texture_env_dot3, GL_MESA_window_pos, GL_NV_packed_depth_stencil, 
    GL_NV_texture_rectangle, GL_NV_vertex_program, GL_ARB_depth_texture, 
    GL_ARB_occlusion_query, GL_ARB_shadow, GL_ARB_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar, GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3, 
    GL_ARB_texture_mirrored_repeat, GL_ARB_window_pos, GL_ATI_envmap_bumpmap, 
    GL_EXT_stencil_two_side, GL_EXT_texture_cube_map, GL_NV_depth_clamp, 
    GL_NV_vertex_program1_1, GL_APPLE_client_storage, GL_APPLE_packed_pixels, 
    GL_APPLE_vertex_array_object, GL_ARB_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program, GL_ARB_fragment_shader, GL_ARB_shader_objects, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_program, GL_ARB_vertex_shader, GL_ATI_draw_buffers, 
    GL_ATI_texture_env_combine3, GL_EXT_shadow_funcs, GL_EXT_stencil_wrap, 
    GL_MESA_pack_invert, GL_MESA_ycbcr_texture, GL_ARB_depth_clamp, 
    GL_ARB_fragment_program_shadow, GL_ARB_half_float_pixel, 
    GL_ARB_point_sprite, GL_ARB_shading_language_100, GL_ARB_sync, 
    GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two, GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object, 
    GL_ATI_blend_equation_separate, GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate, 
    GL_OES_read_format, GL_ARB_color_buffer_float, GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object, 
    GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc, GL_ARB_texture_rectangle, 
    GL_EXT_pixel_buffer_object, GL_EXT_texture_compression_rgtc, 
    GL_EXT_texture_rectangle, GL_EXT_texture_sRGB, GL_ARB_framebuffer_object, 
    GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit, GL_EXT_framebuffer_multisample, 
    GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil, GL_APPLE_object_purgeable, 
    GL_ARB_vertex_array_object, GL_ATI_separate_stencil, GL_EXT_draw_buffers2, 
    GL_EXT_gpu_program_parameters, GL_EXT_texture_env_combine, 
    GL_EXT_texture_sRGB_decode, GL_EXT_timer_query, GL_OES_EGL_image, 
    GL_ARB_copy_buffer, GL_ARB_half_float_vertex, GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, 
    GL_ARB_texture_rg, GL_ARB_texture_swizzle, GL_ARB_vertex_array_bgra, 
    GL_EXT_separate_shader_objects, GL_EXT_texture_swizzle, 
    GL_EXT_vertex_array_bgra, GL_NV_conditional_render, 
    GL_ARB_ES2_compatibility, GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, 
    GL_ARB_explicit_attrib_location, GL_ARB_fragment_coord_conventions, 
    GL_ARB_provoking_vertex, GL_ARB_sampler_objects, GL_ARB_seamless_cube_map, 
    GL_ARB_shader_texture_lod, GL_EXT_provoking_vertex, GL_EXT_texture_snorm, 
    GL_MESA_texture_signed_rgba, GL_ARB_robustness
32 GLX Visuals
48 GLXFBConfigs:
```

Comment: what resolution are you running? - the error message looks like it was expecting a 1024x768 display

Comment: 1366x768 - i tried to switch to 1280x768, but didn't work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I've heard, this package simply doesn't work on Intel graphics chipsets.  Supposedly the vendor is working on a fix, and I'm trying to get someone to update the package description to indicate this limitation, but for now there's probably not much you can do to get it working.

This link might be relevant for you:
https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Pay/FAQs/Refunds

Comment: can you add a weblink to where you have heard that this is to be fixed?

Comment: Nope, sorry.  I heard it directly from one of the Software Center team over IRC.  They pointed me at this question because they thought someone might want a refund, and I handle those.

Comment: ok - perhaps just add to your answer that you work for canonical and this is your recommendation for intel users.

Answer (score 1):

I also had a problem with this game not working but I do not have intel graphics.

I have however managed to get round it

I at first had the demo version which worked perfectly. When I purchased the full version it looked like it was not working. Click to start nothing happens, but because I have Indicator-multiload always running I noticed my cpu usage increasing as I would expect it to with running the game.
Opening system monitor revealed that it was a running process.

Below I am pasting my correspondence with Canonical isd-support

Email 1

> > I purchased Chainz Galaxy from USC after successfully playing the Demo, however the full version does not seem to work.
> >
> > When starting the game nothing appears to happen but it does show up in system monitor and has to be killed from there.
> >
> > I would prefer to play the game than have a refund but if that is not possible can I please have a refund
> >     I have pasted my receipt below, If you require any further information please ask

E-mail 2

> > In an effort to get this working I have tried a few things, and now seem to be able to get the game working (though not how it is supposed to)
> >
> > I un-installed  the game and deleted the save file .Chainz Galaxy from the home folder, then re-installed the game.
> >
> > When starting the game it still did not appear however I was able to get to it via Alt&Tab. This however only worked twice.
> >     On the 3rd attempt the game was not showing in the Alt&Tab menu though the game was showing as running in the system monitor.
> >
> > Also on this attempt the Unity interface went haywire, the lense would not show and all the icons in the launcher became squashed so I killed the game from system monitor then logged out and back in again.
> >
> > Seeing as Unity went funny I turned off wobbly windows as I am aware that many compiz affects do not work well with Unity and it was the only affect I was using.
> >
> > Once again I was able to get into the game via Alt&Tab but once again not with every attempt and having to go into system monitor to kill the process. This time it did not affect Unity
> >
> > Next, once I got the game up again I switched off full screen mode from the games options menu. Now it appears consistent and I am able to get to the game at every attempt via Alt&Tab only.
> >
> > I realise that this may lead you to believe that I have insufficient system requirements so i have listed my system below.
> >
> > I also must stress that no problems exist with the demo version
> >
> > OS: Ubuntu 11.10 32 bit
> >
> > Memory: 3.0 GiB
> >
> > Processor: AMD Athlon(tm) 64 X2 Dual Core Processor 6000+ × 2
> >
> > Graphics: GeForce 9300 GE/PCI/SSE2/3DNOW!

To summarise: I can now run the game with no issues by ensuring that it does not start in full screen and to use Alt & Tab to bring it on screen

I realise that this different from your problem, but it may help others who navigate to here experiencing problems.